# How to catch preemption notice in NodeJs when running on a GKE cluster?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running NodeJs services on a Google Kubernetes Cluster with Preemptible VM instances.
Before such a VM shuts down a `"preemption notice"` is sent. (as described in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/preemptible-vms#about))

> Compute Engine sends a preemption notice to the instance in the form of an ACPI G2 Soft Off signal

[source](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#preemption-process)

---

I want to know how to handle this signal from inside my NodeJs service?

Is it enough to do it like this?

```js
process.on('SIGTERM', () => { 
  // do stuff to prepare service for shutdown
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not enough, to make it works you need to add a [shutdown script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-preemptible-instance#handle_preemption) to your container.

In alternative you can install `acpid` in your container and listen its events through [node-acpi](https://github.com/chesles/node-acpi).

Hope this helps.